# Is there any data structures to add a number and query sum of the smallest k numbers?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Is there any data structures with the support of the below 2 operations?

1. Add a integer to the collection
2. Query the sum of the smallest k numbers in the collection, where k is given with the query and can be as big as the size of the collection.

Both operations should have a time complexity of no more than O(logn) where n is the size of the collection.

Comment: @amit.: missed the part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an augmented BST should do the trick here. Take your favorite balanced binary search tree (red/black, AVL, scapegoat, etc.) and have each node store two extra fields:

1. How many nodes are in the node’s left subtree.
2. The sum of all values in the node’s left subtree.

These properties can be maintained as you perform insertions and deletions in time O(log n) each. (If you haven’t seen how to do this, check out CLRS for details. It’s a cool construction!)

Once you’ve done this, insertions can be done in time O(log n) by doing a regular insert followed by fixing up all the updates cached values, which takes a total of O(log n) time.

To get the sum of the k smallest values, you can do a recursive walk of the tree. Specifically, look at the root node. Then:

1. If the root node has exactly k - 1 elements in its left subtree, the sum of the k smallest elements can be found by returning the root’s cached sum (of the k-1 elements to its left) plus the root’s value.
2. If the root has k or more elements in its left subtree, recursively descend to the left subtree and return the sum of its k smallest elements.
3. If the root has m < k - 1 elements in its left subtree, return the root’s cached sum plus the (recursive) sum of the k - m - 1 smallest elements in the root’s right subtree.

This makes a single root-to-leaf pass down the tree, which will take time O(log n).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a variation of [index statistics tree (AKA ranked tree)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree), where in each node, in addition to storing *number of nodes* in this subtree, you also store *sum of nodes*. This can be calculated per node trivially with `self.subtree_sum = left.subtree_sum + right.subtree_sum + self.value`.

Then, finding the sum of all elements up to the `k`th is done identically to finding the `k`th element in order statistics tree, but in addition you also sum the values in addition to the number of nodes.